# How to handle Closure and Static Method Call in Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, closures, expression-trees

The Following Code tries to Create a Func delegate that converts from the original func Argument Type to another type.

```
    public static Delegate Convert<T1, R>(this Func<T1, R> func, Type argType)
    {
       var param = Expression.Parameter(argType);
       var convertedParam = new Expression[] { Expression.Convert(param, typeof(T1))};

        var call = Expression.Convert(
            func.Target == null || func.Target is Closure
                ? Expression.Call(func.Method, Expression.Constant(func.Target), convertedParam[0])// this path causes the error
                : Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(func.Target), func.Method, convertedParam), typeof(R));

        var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(argType, typeof(R));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, call, param);
        return lambda.Compile();// BUG: 'MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.

    }
```

My problem starts when the Func contains a closure as Target, lambda.Compile() bugs saying "Method Info must be a runtime MethodInfo Object" i suspect it's because the method is static.

Can someone please explain to me what i am doing wrong? and why? i obviously don't understand Expressions well enough to fix this on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should call [`Expression.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.invoke), which will call a delegate directly.

Pass it `Expression.Constant(func)`.

Comment: Thanks so much, i just tried it and it seems to work...Thanks again!